# Getting Google cloud cdn's domain name and benefits of edge locations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

Coming from AWS/cloudfront background I want to know the base domain of google's CDN which I can't find anywhere. In Cloudfront, domain such as xyzid.cloudfront.net available in the list of cloudfront distributions.

I need to store objects in google's bucket and server via google's CDN for better performance. I have read lot of tutorials which explains how to link cdn with bucket via load-balancer. But in the end it gives me only IP address, via which I am able to access the bucket's content successfully.

Since IP will be in a particular location, whereas in case of cloudfront it gives domain such as xyzid.cloudfront.net which resolves to nearest IP address based on the location of user. I am highly doubtful, how using IP as a base domain will give the advantage of 90+ edge locations of google.

I think I am missing something big here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Coming from AWS/cloudfront background I want to know the base domain
>   of google's CDN which I can't find anywhere.

When you configure a Google CDN, you need to configure a Load Balancer and enable the CDN feature. The address of the CDN is the address of the load balancer. This is the case for caching compute instances and Cloud Storage.

> Since IP will be in a particular location, ...

Incorrect assumption that an IP address is tied to a location in GCP. Google supports a global IP address where the IP address itself is global in scope and resolves to the closest (configured) edge location for routing. This technology is called [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast). The same technology used for Global Domain Name servers.

[EDIT with additional information]

There are two types of public external IP addresses. Gobal and Regional. Use a Global IP address for Global HTTP(S) Load Balancers. Regional IP addresses are used for VM instances, Network Load Balancers and most other services.

Comment: Thanks John, didn't know about Anycast. In that case I can use IP address to make A record in my DNS and use domain name as well. Also I read in a article(https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-cdn-test/) "Google will by default give you an ephemeral IP, and it’s strongly recommended to get one static public IP for the LB." Why static IP is recommended, can google change ephemeral Anycast IP anytime?

Comment: When you create a static IP address, the address is assigned to your project. Otherwise you have a temporary IP address that might change. For Internet resources that are public you do not want to use ephemeral (temporary) IP addresses. There are two types of static IP addresses. Gobal and Regional. Use a Global IP address for Global HTTP(S) Load Balancers. Regional IP addresses can be used for VM instances or Network Load Balancers.

Comment: Thanks John. These are the new things which were not there in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage objects can be accessed through the URLs describes at [1].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints

Comment: Thanks German! These are end-points for cloud-storage, which probably won't give benefits of cdn at 100+ edge locations.